# Error when I want to change my mappings

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, express, code-first

```
public class MovieTotal:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get;set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Movie mov = new Movie();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(GetPropert("MovieName")).HasColumnName("Actors");
    }

    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Movie,string>> GetPropert(string  properName)
    {
        // Func<Movie, string> dele = 
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Movie, string>> exp = k => (string)(typeof(Movie).GetProperty(properName).GetValue(k, null));
        return exp ;
    }

    public string GetColumnName(string value)
    {
        return "Actors";
    }

    public MovieTotal()
    {   
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MovieTotal6;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

> The expression 'k => Convert(Movie.GetProperty(value(MovieTotal+ <>c__DisplayClass0).properName).GetValue(k, null))' is not a valid  property expression. It must be of the form 'e => e.Property[.Property]'.

Comment: Where and when does the exception occur? You won't be able to use `GetProperty` in a linq query by the way because it cannot be translated into SQL.

Comment: Hi,I got the error in my test page when I want to get the data of movie, have another way to satisfy my requirment that mapping the class and the column by using a pair of string values?     Thanks,Ivan

Comment: What are you trying to do in `OnModelCreating`? There are standard methods to set the column name of a property. I don't see the need for any dynamic approach there.

Comment: Here is my requirment:If the name of column in db have changed,we can manage a xml file and build a new mapping relationship without changing the code.For example,at first,the property Movie.MovieName was mapping the table Movie's colomn MovieName as default.But if we had changed the column MovieName to Col_MovieName,we want to make that mapping relationshiop still  be correct by add a pair of value like this " <Mapping Property="MovieName">Col_MovieName<Mapping/>" in a xml file without change the code.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't do that. Your current method (if it worked) only supports string properties. Why not re-compile your code when the database changes? One should not change such minor database details too often anyway. Because of mappings it is no point to postpone such modifications until "real" (structural) changes are to be made.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I think your are right.Actually if some columns' names have changed, changing the code may be simple and effective.

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold,by the way,I want to  know what does your words "There are standard methods to set the column name of a property", do it mean using the columnattribute(column(Name="Col_MovieName")) on the property?

Comment: Yes, or `modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(m => m.Name).HasColumnName()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression that is passed to the Property method is verified that it is a MemberExpression whose .Member property is a PropertyInfo. If it is not the exception you are seeing will be thrown. You can find the actual code that does that here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7fb31c1526d0#src%2fEntityFramework%2fUtilities%2fExpressionExtensions.cs (look for GetSimplePropertyAccess method)
Now the reason why Property() method takes an Expression is not to make people learn Expression Trees and intricacies of Linq but to give a better experience when coding - namely when you start typing the lambda expression in the brackets Intellisense will show you all the properties on the given entity which is helpful. In addition lambda expression is strongly typed so if you mistyped the property your program will not compile. Consider having property name as string in the Property() method - coding would become cumbersome - firstly you would not get the help from the intellisense so you would have to always remember (or check) what properties a given entity has. Secondly if you mistyped the name an exception will be thrown at runtime when the property could not be found rather than at compile time. 
Take a look at Gert Arnold's comment. I believe this is the solution to your problem and answer to your question.